# Assistance with pseudocoding

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, logic, pseudocode

From the viking code school engineering principles prep course:

10 friends are sitting in a circle around a table and decide to play a new game. In it, they count up through the numbers from 1 to 100. The first person says "1", the second says "2" and so on... but with a few catches:

Whenever the number is divisible by 7, they switch directions. So person 6 will say "6", person 7 will say "7", then person 6 again will say "8".
Whenever the number is divisible by 11, they skip the next person.

Pseudocode a program that will determine which player is the one to say "100".
How does one begin figuring out the logic to this one?

Comment: You could run the algorithm until you reach 100. Or, work it out once for 10 people and return the answer, which is just 1 number.

Comment: @SimeonVisser How would you work _"it out once for 10 people and return the answer, which is just 1 number?"_

Comment: @AaditMShah: if it's always 10 people and if the algorithm is always the same then you can work it out on paper / notepad and return the answer (no code needed, just "return n;".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oftentimes in programming, choosing a suitable data structure can drastically simplify the algorithm for solving a particular problem. Your problem can be elegantly solved using a [circular doubly-linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list#Circular_doubly-linked_lists). Since there are ten friends sitting in a circle, we'll put them into the linked list as follows:

```
                   next   +-------+   next
               +--------->|       |----------+
               |          |   1   |          |
               |       +--|       |<--+      v
           +-------+   |  +-------+   |  +-------+
           |       |   |              |  |       |
       +-->|  10   |<--+ prev    prev +--|   2   |---+
       |   |       |                     |       |   |
  next |   +-------+                     +-------+   | next
       |       |                             ^       v
   +-------+   | prev                   prev |   +-------+
   |       |   |                             |   |       |
   |   9   |<--+                             +---|   3   |
   |       |                                     |       |
   +-------+                                     +-------+
     ^   |                                         ^   |
next |   | prev                               prev |   | next
     |   v                                         |   v
   +-------+                                     +-------+
   |       |                                     |       |
   |   8   |---+                             +-->|   4   |
   |       |   |                             |   |       |
   +-------+   | prev                   prev |   +-------+
       ^       v                             |       |
  next |   +-------+                     +-------+   | next
       |   |       |                     |       |   |
       +---|   7   |--+ prev    prev +-->|   5   |<--+
           |       |  |              |   |       |
           +-------+  |   +-------+  |   +-------+
               ^      +-->|       |--+       |
               |          |   6   |          |
               +----------|       |<---------+
                   next   +-------+   next
```

For example, in JavaScript you could write it as:

```js
var firstFriend = toList([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);

function Node(prev, data, next) {
    this.prev = prev;
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}

function toList(array) {
    var length = array.length;
    if (length === 0) throw new Error("empty array");
    var root = new Node(null, array[0], null), node = root, i = 1;
    while (i < length) node = node.next = new Node(node, array[i++], null);
    return (root.prev = node).next = root;
}
```

Now, we can solve the problem using two mutually recursive functions: one for the friends counting in the forward direction and one for the friends counting in the reverse direction:

```js
var answer = forward(1, firstFriend);

function forward(count, friend) {
    if (count      === 100) return friend.data;
    if (count % 7  === 0 &&
        count % 11 === 0)   return reverse(count + 1, friend.prev.prev);
    if (count % 7  === 0)   return reverse(count + 1, friend.prev);
    if (count % 11 === 0)   return forward(count + 1, friend.next.next);
                            return forward(count + 1, friend.next);
}

function reverse(count, friend) {
    if (count      === 100) return friend.data;
    if (count % 7  === 0 &&
        count % 11 === 0)   return forward(count + 1, friend.next.next);
    if (count % 7  === 0)   return forward(count + 1, friend.next);
    if (count % 11 === 0)   return reverse(count + 1, friend.prev.prev);
                            return reverse(count + 1, friend.prev);
}
```

Putting it all together, the answer is `1`:

```js
var firstFriend = toList([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);

var answer = forward(1, firstFriend);

alert(answer);

function Node(prev, data, next) {
    this.prev = prev;
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}

function toList(array) {
    var length = array.length;
    if (length === 0) throw new Error("empty array");
    var root = new Node(null, array[0], null), node = root, i = 1;
    while (i < length) node = node.next = new Node(node, array[i++], null);
    return (root.prev = node).next = root;
}

function forward(count, friend) {
    if (count      === 100) return friend.data;
    if (count % 7  === 0 &&
        count % 11 === 0)   return reverse(count + 1, friend.prev.prev);
    if (count % 7  === 0)   return reverse(count + 1, friend.prev);
    if (count % 11 === 0)   return forward(count + 1, friend.next.next);
                            return forward(count + 1, friend.next);
}

function reverse(count, friend) {
    if (count      === 100) return friend.data;
    if (count % 7  === 0 &&
        count % 11 === 0)   return forward(count + 1, friend.next.next);
    if (count % 7  === 0)   return forward(count + 1, friend.next);
    if (count % 11 === 0)   return reverse(count + 1, friend.prev.prev);
                            return reverse(count + 1, friend.prev);
}
```

Solving it manually to check for correctness:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  | 10  |
+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 12  |     | 11  | 10  |  9  |  8  |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 14  | 13  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 15  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 16  | 17  | 18  | 19  | 20  | 21  |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 25  | 24  | 23  |     | 22  |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 28  | 27  | 26  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 29  | 30  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 31  | 32  | 33  |     | 34  | 35  |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 40  | 39  | 38  | 37  | 36  |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 42  | 41  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 43  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 44  |     | 45  | 46  | 47  | 48  | 49  |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 55  | 54  | 53  | 52  | 51  | 50  |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 56  |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 57  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 58  | 59  | 60  | 61  | 62  | 63  |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 67  |     | 66  | 65  | 64  |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 70  | 69  | 68  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 71  | 72  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 73  | 74  | 75  | 76  | 77  |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 80  | 79  | 78  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     | 84  | 83  | 82  | 81  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 85  | 86  | 87  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 88  |     | 89  | 90  | 91  |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 95  | 94  | 93  | 92  |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 98  | 97  | 96  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | 99  |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 100 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Although this solution is recursive, every recursive program can be converted into a non-recursive program using a stack. The pseudocode for this program is very simple. Hence, I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out.

Comment: not to revive something beyond dead, but I came back to look at this nearly a year later, and I must say, this was a fantastic solution. Didn't make any sense to me at the time, but having spent time with data structures, couldn't have come up with a better solution myself!

Answer (score -1):

What I did was create a for loop to 100, and inside have a variable that keeps track of the direction, and another keeping track of the current player. I used if statements inside the loop to decide whether the direction should be switched or the current player incremented or decremented.

Here's what I ended up with, it's not pretty but it should work:

```
int curPlayer = 1;
int direction = 1;

for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    if(i % 7 == 0 && direction == 1)
    {
        direction = 0;
    }
    else if(i % 7 == 0)
    {
        direction = 1;
    }

    if(i % 11 == 0 && direction == 1)
    {
        curPlayer++;
    }
    else if(i % 11 == 0)
    {
        curPlayer--;
    }

    if(direction == 1)
    {
        curPlayer++;
    }
    else
    {
        curPlayer--;
    }

    if(curPlayer > 10)
    {
        curPlayer = curPlayer - 10;
    }
    else if(curPlayer < 1)
    {
        curPlayer = curPlayer + 10;
    }
}

return curPlayer;
```

In pseudocode:

```
set curPlayer to 1
set direction to 1

for(i is 1 to 100)
{
    if i is divisible by 7 and direction is 1
    {
        set direction to 0
    }
    else if i is divisible by 7
    {
        set direction to 1
    }

    if i is divisible by 11 and direction is 1
    {
        increment curPlayer
    }
    else if i is divisible by 11
    {
        decrement curPlayer
    }

    if direction is 1
    {
        increment curPlayer
    }
    else
    {
        decrement curPlayer
    }

    if curPlayer is larger than 10 {
        subtract 10 from curPlayer
    }

    if curPlayer is less than 1 {
        add 10 to curPlayer
    }
}

return curPlayer
```

Comment: can you quickly put this into pseudocode? Also, when the count is divisible by 11, should curPlayer be increased by 2, since the next person is being skipped? I'm also having trouble understanding why, if the number is divisible by both 7 AND the direction=1, you set direction equal to 0. 

Also, does this deal with numbers divisible by both 11 and 7, in which case the direction is reversed AND the next person is skipped?

Also, should the "for" loop continue up to 100?

Comment: When the count is divisible by 11, `curPlayer` is first incremented or decremented by one, but then in `if(direction == 1)`, `curPlayer` is incremented or decremented again, which adds up to a total of 2 either decremented or incremented. `direction` represents which direction the circle is going, so if `i` is divisible by 7, the direction needs to switch to either zero or one, depending where it is already at. Divisible by both 11 and 7 is taken into account for since it goes through both if statements. The loop goes from 0 to 99, which is 100, just as 1 to 100 is 100.

Comment: I realize I didn't take into account that there are only 10 players, I'm making some edits.

Comment: It's not really pseudocode if all you are doing is making your program read more like English by removing parentheses around `if` statements and replacing symbols with words. Pseudocode should be more descriptive and more easy to understand than the actual code itself. Pseudocode is a description of the algorithm used to solve the problem whereas code is the solution to the problem. Nowhere in your "pseudocode" have you explained your algorithm. The reader is forced to try to understand the algorithm by reading the code. Just giving code and saying this is the pseudocode is not enough. Explain

Comment: @AaditMShah Can you show an example for pseudocode as you described it , a link to an example? I learned it just as a way to make code easier for people to understand by taking out the details that are necessary for the computer to read. I know I could have explained the variables instead of just stating `increment curPlayer`, but that seems superfluous and not what you meant by "explained your algorithm". Thanks!